# How do I include MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in Swift Package Manager Package.swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, header-files, metal, swift-package-manager

In a internal .metal file in the `ShaderPackage` defined in `Package.swift`, I want to include an internal header. That header is nested deeply inside the `include` folder and I don't want to have to use the relative path. In a non Swift Package Manager (SPM) project, I can just set `MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` to recursively include all subfolders, then include `Header.h` anywhere in the project without needing to know exactly where it is. (This isn't about exposing either file beyond the package bounds - just an internal-to-package question).

**First question:** Is there a way to set `MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` from a Package.swift (manifest file for SPM)? [Doesn't look like](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/PackageDescription.md#target) there's any build settings for Metal, only C, CXX, and Swift. Whatever settings I add to `cSettings` in the form of `.headerSearchPath("include/subfolder")` doesn't get picked up by Metal, nor `.cXXSettings` or `.swiftSettings`. Can I define a custom setting somehow?

**Second**: If there's a way to set `MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`, can I do it recursively? Or do I have to add each subfolder within `include`? Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @NilsHolgerson sadly no. I wasn't able to properly separate out Metal files into a package as a result. Let me know if you find a way! Current state of the repo: https://github.com/dgattey/genera